# How to use encrypted password in glassfish4 datasoruce

Tags: glassfish

I've created a data source in Glassfish 4 and I want to encrypt the password in the data source.So, is there any scenario to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of encrypting password I've used password alias in Glassfish 4.

1. create password alias

   - asadmin > create-password-alias
   - Enter the value for the aliasname operand > my_alias
   - Enter the alias password > *****
   - Enter the alias password again > *****
2. edit the JDBC Connection Pool Password property as

   - ${ALIAS=my_alias}
     [Glassfish 4 JDBC Connection Pool Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28U8f.png)

if anybody has another scenario, please mention it.